# Android: ScrollView Issue

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I have had a number of problems with ScrollViews. Recently I tried to create a LinearView which content exceeds the screen size so I created the new layout with parent element ScrollView and set its width and height to custom values (the layout has to appear as dialog - not filling the whole screen).

When the element is selected the red border appears to embrace the rectangle of predefined ScrollView LayoutWidth and LayoutHeight which is OK. Then I placed inside the LinearView and set the values LayoutWidth and LayoutHeight to fill_parent.

Then when I started to add the elements into the LinearLayout the border (red lile) wrapped the inserted elements, not the whole parent ScrollView.

So when the content of the LinearLayout (child of ScrollView) exceeded the size of parent ScrollView the scroll didn't appear and the bottom elements are simply invisible.

Anyway.. in that case the XML content was too extensive to post the question here and now I'm having the same problem with the more simple example.

The following part of the layout is intended to be a scrollable EditText (in case the user input exceeds the primary size of the widget). I wanted to set the EditText height to 120px, so I set the parent ScrollView height to 120px and the child EditText to fill_parent. Again in this case the EditText doesn't fill the whole ScrollView area but a single line:

```
 <ScrollView android:layout_height="120px" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<EditText android:id="@+id/txtContent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="TestContent">
</EditText>
</ScrollView>
```

Does anyone know how to reshape the content above so the EditText fills the parent control and in case the user's input exceeds the control size the scroll appears?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

Below are the screenshots of the layout

*removed dead ImageShack link*
*removed dead ImageShack link*

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Your EditText should have a height of `wrap_content`. `fill_parent` has no meaning in a `ScrollView`. If you want the `EditText` to fill your `ScrollView` when it's content is smaller than the `ScrollView`, use `android:fillViewport="true"` on the `ScrollView`.

Comment: But with `ScrollView` having `android:fillViewport="true"` create a strange trouble for me. In fragment there is a scrollview and within it is a table layout with dynamically created table rows at the run time. After that if ad banner gets loaded and i make is visible so due to shift in fragment size my child table rows gets disappeared. This doesn't happened if i set fillViewPort to false!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, as Romain said, scrollview needs following combo.

1. for ScrollView `android:fillViewport="true"`
2. for child of ScrollView `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Yes. There were ocassions where I got weird behavior when I set it to fill_parent.

Comment: I did the same , but then i am not able to scroll ? can you help me out to trying to understand what could be the problem ??