# Shrink textview when when editing is finished

Tags: android, textview

I have a multi-line text view that can get quite large. When the user is actually editing it I want to expand as needed -- but then collapse it again down to a single line when it's no longer being edited.

Example: During the edit the textview may have many lines and look like this

Lots of really long notes 
on multiple liness

When focus is lost, I want to contract the view back to single line so that look like:
Lots of really long...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been several questions like this one, please check here:

[TextView expand animation like in Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927977/textview-expand-animation-like-in-android-market)

[Android: Expand/collapse animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946295/android-expand-collapse-animation)

[Android EditText won't take up remaining space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830669/android-edittext-wont-take-up-remaining-space)

[How to scale/resize text to fit a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596452/how-to-scale-resize-text-to-fit-a-textview)

Some of these links include the sliding animation for the textviews. I hope this helps!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Tried wrapping it inside a `ScrollView`?