# How do I give a gridLayout the ability to scroll vertically and horizontally at the start of the application in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, scroll, grid-layout

So imagine a view with 9 tiles that looks something like this:

(tile1) (tile2) (tile3)

(tile4) (tile5) (tile6)

(tile7) (tile8) (tile9)

One tile takes up most of the screen. I have this set up already with a horizontalscrollgroup nested inside a scrollgroup to enable both horizontal and vertical scrolling but the problem is that the view starts off with tile1 in the center of the screen. I want the view to start off with tile 5 in the center and give the user the ability to scroll up, down, left, right, and diagonally. How can I implement this?
I guess my main issue is centering the view on tile5. Also is this is a good way to implement both horizontal and vertical scrolling or is there a more proper way of doing this?

Sorry I'm a beginner with mobile ui programming.

Comment: may work :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148175/android-horizontal-and-vertical-scroll-for-gridlayout

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">   


         </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
```