# Why Tabbar shows white shadow when it overlaps buttons?

Tags: android, button, tabbar

I am facing this strange problem. In my app, I have a tabbar at the bottom of the screen. In this screen I have some EditTexts and Buttons.

Now my problem is that if the app is running on small devices, when tabbar somehow shows up overlapping the buttons, then a white shadow shows up over the tabbar(as shown in the attached image). This shadow doesnot show up if the tabbar is not overlapping any widget.

I just want to know if this is natural behaviour of android or I can get rid of it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image: fulltab]

Comment: Use `ScrollView` for this..!!

Comment: @SpK : I am already using scrollbar. The screen is scrollable.Its just that while scrolling , when the buttons and tabs are meeting with each other, then this effect is showing up.

Comment: You're also having same shadow effect like what i've?

Comment: what kind of effect are you having?

Comment: Ok. This sees a little different. But you are quite experienced in Android. Do you think my problem is same as yours? Maybe in my case , line is not showing up because I have completely filled the tabbar with tabbuttons and my tabbuttons are not smaller in width than the tabbar. So line is just sticking with the tabbar and is not visible. Only that shadow is showing up.

Comment: I have uploaded the full image.

Comment: Lets continue this discussion [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This show is not show by Tabs, it is default fade effect of scroll view, You can remove this by set it to none. For this you have to add this property in scroll view

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

under the Scrollview tag of this screen.

Comment: it works. Actually it was a problem of scrollview , not tabview. So I defined this attribute in scrollview of this page. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Fading edge color is controlled by the `android:cacheColorHint` attribute.

Try below code -

```
ScrollView android:cacheColorHint="#ff000000" android:background="#ffffffff" />
```

instead of these colors you can give your desired color. Try below links -

1. [ScrollView Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2034666/940096)
2. [ScrollView FadingEdge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640877/how-to-set-the-color-of-an-android-scrollview-fading-edge/3021192#3021192)